# Magazine App with login feature only, but offering no In-App Purchase - will it be rejected?

Tags: ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I am currently concepting an app which shall be setup for multiple mobile Systems, like iOS, Android, Windows.

The app shall distribute publications, for which a login is required. This login can only be purchased from the publishers website.

The idea is, to not having to create in-app setup for all OS systems, but only do this on the website of the publisher. I am aware, that apple does not allow for the app to point to that website though.

Is anyone aware, if Apple would allow for such a concept? I was considering to allow users to read a few publications without the need to login, to pacify apple ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video and cloud storage) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app, as long as there is no button or external link in the App to purchase the approved content."